# MySQL Join Many to Many as single rows

Tags: sql, mysql, join, pivot

I know there's got to be a way to do this, but for the life of me I can't figure it out:

I have 3 tables I want to join together (simplified to illustrate):

```
users
uid mail
1   qq@qq.com
2   ww@ww.com
3   ee@ee.com

profile_fields
fid name        label
1   full_name   Full Name
2   phone       Phone

profile_values
uid fid value
1   1   Q Q
1   2   5555555555
2   1   Ww Ww
3   2   4444525411
```

I'd like to get results of the form:

```
uid mail        full_name   phone
1   qq@qq.com   Q Q     5555555555
2   ww@ww.com   Ww Ww       NULL
3   ee@ee.com   NULL        44445454111
```

I've tried various SELECTs with different JOIN conditions but I can't seem to figure out how to get the rows of profile_fields to be my columns in my SELECT

EDIT:  I've also tried googling around, but I can't seem to figure out how to phrase this to google.

Comment: Updated - missing rows probably because I was joining to the `PROFILE_VALUES` table rather than LEFT JOINing for users without records in the `PROFILE_VALUES` table.

Comment: I've tried making it a left join, still only getting on row.  I'm going to look as using Views Bonus Pack to make at least this report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT u.uid,
       u.mail,
       MAX(CASE WHEN pf.name = 'full_name' THEN pv.value END) AS full_name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN pf.name = 'phone' THEN pv.value END) AS phone
  FROM USERS u
  LEFT JOIN PROFILE_VALUES pv ON pv.uid = u.uid
  JOIN PROFILE_FIELDS pf ON pf.fid = pv.fid
                        AND pf.name IN ('full_name', 'phone')
GROUP BY u.uid, u.mail
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is called a pivot.  MySQL doesn't support pivoting natively, but you can do it using the query OMG Ponies posted.

However, if you have to support an arbitrary number of profile fields, you would have to build the SQL dynamically.

Comment: It's technically arbritrary, but for my purposes I can just maintain the query by hand.  In the future I might try to figure out a way to do this via a Stored Procedure and be able to generate the query dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in general you can't do what you want. Even if @OMG Ponies example is correct it won't work for other values of profile_field names.

You can try writing some code to generate a query for different values of profile_fields based on actual profile_fields.

Or you can make simple many-to-many join and analyse data in other program/code.

Comment: That would have worked, but the problem is I'm using the SQL query to generate an XLS report, so I kind of need to to be in pure SQL.  I'm investigating using a Drupal module to do this, but I'm not sure if it can export as XLS.